# Metabo HC260 planer thicknesser blades

Tags: thickness-planer, blade, planer

I have Metabo HC260 planer/thicknesser (or jointer/planer if you must) and I bought a new set of blades for it. The original blades have a little notch on the back side where an adjustment screw sits (it has a flange). The blades I bought on the other hand don't have that notch. Now I'm wondering if it is still safe to install those blades?

I'm fully aware of how setting them up became infinitely more complex, but I was just wondering if that little notch plays a part in safely keeping that blade in place? (The last thing I want is a blade flying around thrown at 6500 rpm).

The blades I bought have exactly the same dimensions as the original ones.

If it's still unclear what I'm talking about then this is shown in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uXh1fx6JE0 (from 3:00).

Comment: PS> The only reason I bought those blades was that they were a lot cheaper for a very comparable quality (20 GBP vs 190 GBP)

Comment: Watching a bit of the video, it appears that all  notches extend to the bottom of the cutting blade which means that the blade can be pulled out if the bolts are loose.  IMO, this implies that the notch has nothing to do with holding the blade in place.  IT appears that the bolts are fully responsible for that.  BTW if you have a grinding tool  it may be possible to create notches, although the blade will be quite hard.

Comment: Thanks, I only have angle grinder, but I suppose that can easily overheat the blade and ruin it and is probably not precise enough to do the trick. I would guess that they are cutting the notches prior to hardening, but I'm not an expert on metal working so just a wild guess..

Comment: Ultimately I found 6 blades for 99EUR +10EUR for shipping in Germany and ordered those. Safety aside it's simply impossible to get those blades to correct position.